# Math operation with conditional and boolean

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements, boolean-expression

I am reverse engineering a python script that is parsing an XML file into a different data file type. In doing so, I ran across a very elegant line of code:

```
nyear += (1900, 2000)[nyear < 83]
```

I was wondering if anyone knows what this operation is called in Python? I have never seen syntax like this in Python before.

By the way, the results of a couple `nyear` values would be as follows:

```
>>> nyear = 17    
>>> nyear += (1900, 2000)[nyear < 83]    
2017    
>>> nyear = 83    
>>> nyear += (1900, 2000)[nyear < 83]    
1983
```

Comment: `nyear < 83` returns a boolean (`True` or `False`) that is converted into 0 if `False` or 1 if `True`. So you are indexing the tuple `(1900, 2000)` at 0 or 1, depending on whether or not the condition is met. Conditional indexing is what I would call this.

Answer (score 1):

This is just tuple indexing.  In most cases a better idiom is

```
2000 if nyear < 83 else 1900
```